# Triggering WebChromeClient onRequestFocus

Tags: java, android, android-webview, webchromeclient

I'm trying to trigger `WebChromeClient.onRequestFocus()` callback.
In order to acquire information on when it is called, I've dived into android project tests.

I've googled up [test case of WebChromeClient](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/66a3677e838e6ed1f63f89918ce8cf4e6372ccae/tests/tests/webkit/src/android/webkit/cts/WebChromeClientTest.java) from 2009 and created following piece of code to reproduce the test behaviour, which seems not to work.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Activity activity = this;
    final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView2);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            super.onCloseWindow(window);
            Log.i("", "================ onCloseWindow()===============================================================");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture,
                                      Message resultMsg) {
            WebView childView = new WebView(activity);
            childView.setWebChromeClient(this);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(childView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            Log.i("", "================ onCreateWindow()===============================================================");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestFocus(WebView view) {
            Log.i("", "================ onRequestFocus()===============================================================");
        }
    });


    webView.loadData("<html><body onLoad='"
            + "childWindow = window.open();"
            + "childWindow.document.title = \"javascript child window\";"
            + "childWindow.document.write(\"javascript child window\");"
            + "childWindow.focus();"
            + "setTimeout(function(){childWindow.close();}, 10000);"
            + "'><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
```

Logcat of the debugging session confirms that `onCreateWindow()` and `onCloseWindow()` functions are called, no `onRequestFocus()` call though.

Any ideas?

I use API level 19 (Android 4.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Create webpage with two frames

```
<html>
<frameset rows=20%,80%>
    <frame src="frame1.html" name="myFrame1" />
    <frame src="frame2.html" name="myFrame2" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

and place a link in frame1.html with target set to myFrame2

```
<a id="link" href="frame3.html" target="myFrame2">Click me!</a>
```